# Let $f$ be measurable and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\frac{1}{\lambda(M)}\int_Mf\ d\lambda \in [a,b]$ Show that: $f(x) \in [a,b]$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Assignment:

> Let $f$ be Lebesgue - measurable and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with the property:
>   $$\frac{1}{\lambda(M)} \cdot \int_Mf\ d\lambda \in [a,b]$$
>   for all Lebesgue - measurable sets $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $0 < \lambda(M) < \infty$.
>
> Show that: $f(x) \in [a,b]$ almost everywhere.

So I need to show that the set $N$ defined as $N:= \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n; \ f(x) \notin [a,b]\}$ has a measure of zero. However, I cannot really see how to go from there and how the property given could help me.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that an equivalent statement (the contrapositive) is: if $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\colon f(x)\notin[a,b]\}$ doesn't have measure zero, then there exists a measurable set $M\subset\Bbb R^n$ with $0<\lambda(M)<\infty$ such that $\frac1{\lambda(M)} \int_M f\, d\lambda \notin [a,b]$. In this formulation, do you have an idea what you might choose as $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $N = \{x:f(x)\notin[a,b]\}$ is not a null set.

Then at least one of $N_1 = \{x:f(x)<a\}$ or $N_2 = \{x:f(x)>b\}$ is not a null set since $N = N_1\cup N_2$

If $N_1$ is not a null set, then (since $f(x)<a$ on $N_1$)

$$\frac{1}{\lambda(N_1)}\int_{N_1}f~d\lambda<\frac{1}{\lambda(N_1)}\int_{N_1}a~d\lambda=a$$

If $N_2$ is not a null set, then(since $f(x)>b$ on $N_2$)

$$\frac{1}{\lambda(N_2)}\int_{N_2}f~d\lambda>\frac{1}{\lambda(N_2)}\int_{N_2}b~d\lambda=b$$

Either way you contradict your assumption.

Comment: Please do not provide (more or less) complete solutions to homework question that do not show much own effort. You are not helping really helping the OP in his own understanding (he should not really have asked the question in the form he did to begin with). I would have prefered something like the comment of @GregMartin. Disclaimer: KitKat seems to be a student of mine :)

Comment: My apologies. Nice detective work though!

Answer (score 0):

Since $[a,b]^{c}$ is open we can write it as a countable union of disjoint intervals. So it is enough to prove that $\lambda(f^{-1}(I))=0$, where $I:={B(x,r)}\subseteq [a,b]^{c}$. Write $E:=f^{-1}(I)$.

If $\lambda(E)>0$, then

$$\left|\frac{1}{\lambda(E)}\int_{E}f d\lambda-x\right|\leq\frac{1}{\lambda(E)}\int_{E}|f-x| d\lambda\leq r$$

a contradiction, since $\frac{1}{\lambda(E)}\int_{E}f d\lambda \in [a,b]$.