# Does $\int_{I} f d\lambda = 0$ imply that $f=0$ $\lambda$-almost everywhere?

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:X\rightarrow R$ for $X \subset R^n$.

I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
\int_{I} f d\lambda = 0
\end{equation}
for all intervals $I \subset R^n$ implies that $f=0$ $\lambda$-almost everywhere on $X$.
I guess the proof would be similar to the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593817/how-to-prove-that-if-forall-x-in-a-b-lebesgue-integral-int-a-xfd-lam).

Take the rectangle $A_r(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}[x_i-r/2,x_i+r/2]$ centered at $x$ with edge length $r$, so $|A_r(x)|=r^n$.
By assumption
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{r^n} \int_{A_r(x)} f d\lambda = 0
\end{equation}
for all $r > 0$.

By Lebesgue differentiation theorem, 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{r^n} \int_{A_r(x)} f d\lambda = 0
\end{equation}
almost everywhere on $X$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030050/let-f-be-measurable-and-a-b-in-mathbbr-with-frac1-lambdam-int-mf?rq=1

Comment: How much is the measure of $I$?

Comment: The measure is the Lebesgue measure, i.e. if $I = I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n$ is the interval in $R^n$, then $\lambda(I) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \lambda(I_i)$ is its measure.